# Is there anyway to record X or O to a data array to check for winner?

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe

I’m building a tic tac toe game. I would like to ask Is there anyway to record X or O (upon clicking on the board) to a data array to check for winner later on?
Specifically, I would like to record data to the below variable 
Thanks.

```
var board = [[‘’,’’,’’],[‘’,’’,’’],[‘’,’’,’’]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There certainly is.
Currently your board seems to be set up like so:

```
-------------
|0,0|0,1|0,2|
-------------
|1,0|1,1|1,2|
-------------
|2,0|2,1|2,2|
-------------
```

You can acces and set these values in your array like so:

```
board[0][0] //the top left cell
```

If you want to set the value of a cell you do it like this:

```
board[0][0] = "X"
```

You can access an entire row of your board like this:

```
board[0]; 
//this would be ["X","",""] right now
```

I hope this helps you understand array access.

(I also suggest removing the jQuery tag, it has no place here. This is raw javascript)